# How to match logits and labels in tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a pre-trained model that has the following architecture.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 200)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 200, 300)          402877800 
_________________________________________________________________
spatial_dropout1d (SpatialDr (None, 200, 300)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 128)               186880    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_v1 (Batc (None, 128)               512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 6)                 774       
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 6)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 403,065,966
Trainable params: 187,910
Non-trainable params: 402,878,056
_________________________________________________________________
```

The `Reshape` layer makes sure that the logits will be the same as the labels

I have a single input data, which is `Tensor` tensorflow object with with s shape of (200,), and labels, which are also a 'Tensor` tensorflow object with a shape of (6,).

**My goal** here is to evaluate a single sample using the `evaluate` method provided by tensorflow keras. To make it easier, I converted `Tensor` objects into numpy. Since the model accepts an input shape of `[None, 200]`, I have to reshape the input data before feeding it to the model. This way, the model will have a logit of the shape (1,6), which then will be reshaped to (6,) by the `Reshape` layer.

```
# Clone model is the keras model
# sample_data.x is the input
# sample_data.y is the label

clone_model.evaluate([sample_data.x.numpy().reshape(1,200)], [sample_data.y.numpy()])
```

But in the end, I received the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,6] and labels shape [6]
     [[{{node loss_4/dense_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:StatefulPartitionedCall]
```

In order to overcome this, I removed the `Reshape` layer and reshape the labels to (1,6) (`sample_data.y.numpy().reshape(1,6)`). But that didn't help, and I ended up with the same error.

I was wondering if someone could point out what I was missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the code that you used to implement your model ?
If you can provide a minimal working example it would be even better!

Comment: Can you clarify if you "I removed the Reshape layer and reshape the labels to (1,6) (sample_data.y.numpy().reshape(1,6))" at the same time, or did you try removing the reshape layer and reshaping the input on separate tries? I believe reshaping the labels alone will solve your issue.

Comment: @GabrielIbagon yes I did that at the same time. I removed the reshape layer, so that the logits will have the shape of (1,6), then I reshaped the labels to have the shape (1,6). But  when I try to evaluate the input and labels to the model, the mdoel changed the label shape to (6,) again.

Comment: Have you tried reshaping the inputs to the following, and removing the square brackets? `clone_model.evaluate(sample_data.x.numpy().reshape(1,200), sample_data.y.numpy().reshape(1,6))`

Comment: Yes , i tried that before. The model still reshaped the labels to (6,). Even after reshaping them both, I still got the same error.

Comment: Ah I think I might know - are you using "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" as the loss? If so, change it to "categorical_crossentropy" with the code I posted in the other comment. If not, can you post your model code (model creation and compilation) so I can recreate your issue?

Comment: @GabrielIbagon Hey! Actually, I've already solved it. And yes you are absolutely correct! it seems that using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` reshaped the labels. I've changed it to the `binary_crossentropy` and it works just fine. Thank you!